# Linq statement returns null

Tags: c#, linq

I have following statement

```
    EmployeeLog objEmpployeeLog = 
             lstEmployeeLog.Where(x => x.EmpId == iEmpId 
                    && x.InDateTime.Value == lastCheckInDate 
                    && x.OutDateTime == null).FirstOrDefault();
```

lstEmpAttnLog is a List, i know it contains the object which has EmpId, InDateTime equal to the argument passed and OutDateTime is null. I saw these values using breakpoint.

I am surprised why it doesn't return the value.

Please help, i am clueless, please guess what could might have gone wrong.

Comment: Some more context would help a lot. How about posting some data? A first step would be to remove parts of your "Where" code until you get some results to see what part might be the culprit.

Comment: The statement looks fine. The problem must be in the list or in the EmployeeLog class.

Comment: FirstOrDefault() will result in a null if no elements are found. If you use First() instead you'll get an exception, put it in a try {} catch(Exception ex) {} block and you'll get some more details

Comment: If your data is round-tripped through a database the precision of your timestamps are probably rounded to the nearest second. Try removing the millisecond part from the value not passed through the db.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FirstOrDefault` returns `null` if no such element is found.
Therefore, you query doesn't match any item.

As Marc pointed out, perhaps your dates don't match in seconds or milliseconds.
You can modify query to look with specific precision:

```
var epsilon = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0);
var logItem = employeeLog.Where(x => x.EmpId == empId 
    && (x.InDateTime.Value - lastCheckInDate) < epsilon
    && x.OutDateTime == null).FirstOrDefault();
```

And please, don't use [Systems Hungarian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation#Systems_vs._Apps_Hungarian) in C# code! It's absolutely pointless, seeing that C# has strong type system and Visual Studio is an advanced IDE.

Comment: Hi gaearon, your solution solved the problem.  I used your code and got the result. But i don't understand what exactly it is doing. Could you please explain var epsilon = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0);
 and (x.InDateTime.Value - lastCheckInDate) < epsilon. What is it doing? Thanks for your great help.

Comment: @nccsim071, two dates are only equal when they match completely, meaning their `Ticks` are equal. If they differ by just one tick (which is ten-millionth of a second), they are considered different. I think your `DateTime` loses precision at some point (e.g. after being stored in a database) and therefore even if hours, minutes and seconds are the same, they still don't match. So instead of checking whether dates are exactly the same, you should check whether their difference is less than desired precision (in our case, one second is enough).

Comment: agreed on the Hungarian.  no need for it as the code wouldn't even *compile* if you make assignments wrong.

Answer (score 3):

My guess would be small difference (seconds, millis,etc) between `x.InDateTime.Value` and `lastCheckInDate`. Try rounding them off to some pre-determined precision.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using a nullable DateTime value for OutDateTime, if you are change

x.OUtDateTime == null to !x.OutDateTime.HasValue